# Symfony PHP Template custom error page

Tags: php, symfony

I am using symfony 2.8 version with php template. Can I create a customized error page using php template?

Comment: Yes you can.  And the process to accomplish it is outlined very well in the symfony cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

In `services.yml`, add a listener on exceptions:

```
listener.exception:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    arguments: ["MyWebsite\\Controller\\ExceptionController::exceptionAction"]
    tags:
        - {name: 'kernel.event_subscriber'}
```

Then your controller is an ordinary one:

```
<?php

namespace MyWebsite\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ExceptionController extends AbstractController
{
    public function exceptionAction(FlattenException $exception)
    {
        $text = $exception->getMessage() ;
        if (isset(Response::$statusTexts[$exception->getStatusCode()])) {
            $text = Response::$statusTexts[$exception->getStatusCode()];
        }
        $response = new Response(null);
        $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
        return $this->render(
            'exception.html.twig',    // Here your template
            ['error' =>$text],
            $response
        );
    }
}
```